# MS SQL having clause issue

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 columns

```
Item    |   Category

Apple      Fruit
Orange     Fruit
Potatoes   Vegetables
```

Required output:

Fruit

I am trying to get the name of the highest Category in terms of quantity which is Fruit. I wrote a MySql query which works on the MySql. But that same query throws an error on MS SQL Server. Any hint would be appreciated.

```
select Cat from (select count(category) as Total,category as cat from test group by category) as S1 group by S1.Total,S1.Cat having max(s1.total)
```

I get an empty result when I run this. But a similar query i created runs fine on MySql:

```
SELECT s2.cats FROM (SELECT s1.cat AS cats, max(s1.counts) AS countings FROM (SELECT count(category) AS counts, category AS cat from test GROUP BY category) AS s1) AS s2
```

Error message i get is: Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

*I WANT TO AVOID USING TOP*

Comment: You should post the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? Pretty ugly but avoids Top. Also, will return all items that have max count, not just an arbitrary one.

Assuming table [Food] with column Category:

```
select category from Food group by Category having COUNT(*) = 
(select max(cnt) from (select COUNT(*) as cnt from Food group by Category) subq)
```